# Is e-mail redirection from some mail to gmail filtered malwares?

Tags: redirect, gmail, malware, virus

I use my old email account for my business, but the service provider does not filter out malware and viruses (any email with any content accepted).
I want to switch to Gmail but I'm not sure whether redirection will pass from Gmail filters or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short: yes, this is actually very common.

If you want to try a GSuite account for Business Gmail, your mail server can send everything to Google servers, and Google can easily filter spam for you. Here's some basic info: https://support.google.com/a/answer/9228551?hl=en (note that this only apply for GSuite accounts, paid service).

If you want to do a very basic forwarding from your own business account to a free @gmail.com account, you still can, and spam/virus will still be filtered out.